# VBA extract unique values based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get a list of distinct value based on a criteria, example : I have a list of stores, and i want to get only distinct value based on retailer criteria "BOULANGER".

[image]

```
Sub distinctValues()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Crit1 As String

LastRow = Sheets("SOURCE").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("SOURCE").Range("B1:B" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("TEST").Range("E2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A12"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is your code doing wrong?  Where is the error? For that matter, where is the question?

Comment: And to add to @ScottCraner, why am I procrastinating on my own project by helping other people's projects?

Comment: @ScottCraner , The code dosen't works, the problem is CriteriaRange:=, it dosen't extract unique value based on this criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should accomplish what you are trying to do; see comments in the code.

```
Sub ListUniqueValues()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'change as needed

    ws1.Range("B1", ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy ws2.Range("C1") 'copy the full range from sheet1
    ws2.Range("C1", ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo 'remove duplicates

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'set lastrow variable

        For i = lRow To 1 Step -1 'Da Loop, from bottom to top
            'change the cell address after "Like" to the cell address where you put your store criteria
            'the line will delete any store name that is not like your store criteria
            'the (& "*") inserts the wildcard after your store criteria you type in your designated cell, e.g. "BOULANGER*"
            If Not ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value Like ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value & "*" Then  '
                ws2.Cells(i, 3).Delete 'delete the cells that do not match your store criteria
            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's partially what I am looking for but with a condition. Of course I want to extract distinct value according to the retailer's condition. Example : If the condition is "BOULANGER" then I want only distinct stores named "BOULANGER".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Criteria Range is not properly set up and/or named on your worksheet.

In the `.AdvancedFilter`, you have:

```
Range(Crit1)
```

which, according to your code, will be interpreted as:

```
Range("BOULANGER")
```

This presumes you have a Named Range somewhere on your Test Worksheet that is named `BOULANGER` and refers to two cells in a column, the first of which contains `Store` and the second contains `BOULANGER`

If you have that set up properly, then your code works.

Note that in your screen shot showing the criteria, the first cell contains `Criteria` and not `Store`.  So even if you had the defined range setup to encompass those two cells, it would not work since the first row has to have an identical name to the column being filtered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a unique range that contains a keyword, something like this should work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OutputUniqueRange(SearchRange As Range, Keyword As String, OutputRange As Range)
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In SearchRange
        With cell
            If InStr(1, .Value2, Keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 And Not dict.exists(.Value2) Then dict.Add .Value2, .Value2
        End With
    Next

    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    OutputRange.Range(OutputRange.Cells(1, 1).Address).Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items())
End Sub

Public Sub TestSub()
    Dim SearchRange         As Range
    Dim Keyword             As String
    Dim OutputRange         As Range

    Keyword = "Boulanger"
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A34")
    Set OutputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    OutputUniqueRange SearchRange, Keyword, OutputRange
End Sub
```

Comment: It did works. The OutputRange is set for Range("B2")  but when I execute th code, the result appear on Range K2.